# Upper bound on least common multiple of consecutive integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am reading through Alan Baker's *Transcendental Number Theory* (don't worry if you don't know the book or the subject - this question is pretty much self-contained). Lemma 1 of Chapter 3 states an upper bound for $\nu(x;k)$, defined to be the least common multiple of the integers $x+1,\ldots,x+k$. The claim is that, for some absolute constant $c$, one has $\nu(x;k)\leq\left(\frac{c(x+k)}{k}\right)^{2k}$. The proof, as quoted from the book, is as follows:

> (...) We write $\nu(x;k)=\nu'\nu''$, where all prime factors of $\nu'$, $\nu''$ are $\leq k$ and $>k$, respectively. Since the exponent to which a prime $p$ divides $\nu'$ is at most $\frac{\log(x+k)}{\log p}$, we have
>   $$\log\nu'\leq\sum\log(x+k)\leq\frac{c'k\log(x+k)}{\log k}$$
>   where the summation is over all primes $p\leq k$, and $c'$, like $c$, $c''$ and $c'''$ below, denotes an absolute constant. **Now we can assume that $k>c''$ and that $x>c''k$ for some sufficiently large $c''$, for otherwise the desired conclusion would follow at once from the simpler upper bounds $(x+k)^k$ and $c^{x+k}$ for $\nu(x;k)$. Thus we see that**
>   $$\nu'\leq\left(\frac{c'''(x+k)}{k}\right)^{2k}\text{.}$$
>   But clearly $\nu''$ divides $\binom{x+k}{k}$, and this does not exceed $\frac{(x+k)^k}{k!}$; the required estimate is now apparent.

I am really confused about the part I wrote in bold. I understand why we can assume that $k>c''$, but I don't understand why we can assume $x>c''k$; in fact, I find it strange that the "easy case" is precisely when $x$ is small compared to $k$, since this is precisely when the asserted bound does not seem useless compared to the easier (and better for $x$ large compared to $k$) bound $(x+k)^k$. Moreover, even assuming those two inequalities, I can't see how the conclusion on $\nu'$ follows.

Any help in understanding this would be appreciated; if anyone sees another way to prove this result I would also like to know it.

Comment: I fixed a typo in your last display (namely I changed $c+k$ to $x+k$ as in the original source). More importantly, I show below that the conclusion holds with $c'''=1$.

Comment: The point is that the lcm of *all* the integers up to x+k is ~ e^{x+k}. Hence if x << k then you get O(1)^k, which matches the quality of the desired bound. Also the bound he’s getting is somewhat useless (but still better since c is absolute) when x is *way* larger than k, but when x is just linearly larger your trivial bound is like a k^k when he’s looking for an O(1)^k.

Comment: @alpoge: It is not true that the lcm of all the integers up to $x+k$ is asymptotically $e^{x+k}$. Instead, the logarithm of this lcm is asymptotically $x+k$. Note also that I gave a detailed answer below.

Comment: :) @GHfromMO You are always catching me using ~ slightly imprecisely in the comments! Good that someone is keeping me honest. Indeed the correct statement is that it is = e^{(x+k) (1+o(1))} by the prime number theorem. But of course Chebyshev suffices to give a bound of O(1)^{x+k}, which suffices for what I was saying above. I certainly agree with your arguments below!!

Comment: @alpoge: Yes, and $O(1)^{x+k}$ is emphasized by Baker as well (see the highlighted text above). Another advice: please put your formulae inside dollar symbols, as in TeX. This site uses TeX!

Comment: Ahh!! Sorry! I always comment on my mobile (while wasting time...) and for some reason the standard app doesn’t render TeX in comments, so I have no way of knowing if I’ve totally screwed the formatting up. Occasionally when I do check the site on my computer I see that I often manage to totally garble everything when I do try to use TeX because I drop a dollar sign somewhere. But I will try to be better about using it! Sorry @GHfromMO !

Comment: @alpoge: I see. Well, my mobile phone does not have internet access, so I could not know that. I bought it for 10 euros, and it had a credit of 10 euros for phone calls. You cannot beat that :-) And it runs JAVA for games!

Comment: Is the "absolute constant" c supposed to be independent of both x and k ?

Comment: @DanielAsimov, yes. All other c', c'', etc. are so too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** Assume first that $k\leq c''$. Then
$$\nu(x;k)\leq(x+k)^k\leq\left(\frac{c''}{k}\right)^{2k}(x+k)^{2k}=\left(\frac{c''(x+k)}{k}\right)^{2k}.$$
So the range $k\leq c''$ is fine as long as $c$ is chosen to satisfy $c\geq c''$.

**2.** Now assume that $x\leq c''k$. Then for some absolute constants $C$ and $C'$,
$$\nu(x;k)\leq C^{x+k}\leq C^{c''k+k}\leq C'^{2k}\leq\left(\frac{C'(x+k)}{k}\right)^{2k}.$$
So the range $x\leq c''k$ is fine as long as $c$ is chosen to satisfy $c\geq C'$.

**3.** By the above, we can assume that $k>c''$ and $x>c''k$, where $c''$ is any prescribed absolute constant. I claim that if $c''$ is sufficiently large in terms of $c'$, then $k>c''$ and $x>c''k$ imply
$$\frac{c'\log(x+k)}{2\log k}\leq\log\frac{x+k}{k}.\tag{$\ast$}$$
This is sufficient, because then the indicated bound for $\log\nu'$ implies
$$\log\nu'\leq\frac{c'k\log(x+k)}{\log k}\leq 2k\log\frac{x+k}{k},$$
which then clearly implies
$$\nu'\leq\left(\frac{x+k}{k}\right)^{2k}.$$
Let us analyze $(\ast)$. It can be rewritten as
$$\log k\leq\left(1-\frac{c'}{2\log k}\right)\log(x+k).$$
We are assuming that $x>c''k$, hence it suffices to show that
$$\log k\leq\left(1-\frac{c'}{2\log k}\right)\log(c''k+k).$$
This is equivalent to
$$\frac{c'}{2}\leq\left(1-\frac{c'}{2\log k}\right)\log(c''+1).$$
We are also assuming that $k>c''$, hence it suffices to verify that
$$\frac{c'}{2}\leq\left(1-\frac{c'}{2\log c''}\right)\log(c''+1).$$
However, it is clear that this inequality holds when $c''$ is sufficiently large in terms of $c'$. Indeed, if $c'$ is fixed and $c''$ tends to infinity, then the left hand side is fixed, while the right hand side tends to infinity. Done.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, we can prove a stronger bound as stated in Baker's book: **The exponent $2$ can in fact be reduced easily to $1$, which is best possible**.

We compare the exponents of a prime $p$ in $(x+1)\cdots (x+k)$ and $\nu(x;k)$. Note that
$$\left\lfloor \frac{x+k}{p^j}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac x{p^j}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac k{p^j}\right\rfloor+\left\{\frac k{p^j}\right\}+\left\{ \frac x{p^j}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x+k}{p^j}\right\}$$
counts the number of multiples of $p^j$ in $x+1, \ldots, x+k$. The last three fractional part terms are either $0$ or $1$.

Let $ap^m$ with $(a,p)=1$ be the largest $p$-power appears in $x+1,\ldots x+k$. Then we expect there is more $p$-power in the product $(x+1)\cdots (x+k)$ than in $\nu(x;k)$. The excess $p$-power is
$$\begin{align}
\nu_p((x+1) &\cdots (x+k))-\nu_p(\nu(x;k)) \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^m \left(\left\lfloor \frac{x+k}{p^j}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac x{p^j}\right\rfloor-1 \right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1 \\p^j\leq k}^m \left(\left\lfloor \frac k{p^j}\right\rfloor+\left\{\frac k{p^j}\right\}+\left\{ \frac x{p^j}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x+k}{p^j}\right\}-1\right)\\
& \ \ \ +\sum_{j=1 \\p^j> k}^m \left(\left\lfloor \frac{x+k}{p^j}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac x{p^j}\right\rfloor-1 \right)\end{align}.
$$
If $p^j>k$, then $ap^m$ is the unique multiple of $p^j$ in $x+1,\ldots, x+k$. Thus, the difference between the floor functions in the second sum is $1$. Then, the second sum must vanish.

Using that the three fractional parts in the first sum is either $0$ or $1$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\nu_p((x+1) &\cdots (x+k))-\nu_p(\nu(x;k)) \\
&=\sum_{j=1 \\p^j\leq k}^m \left(\left\lfloor \frac k{p^j}\right\rfloor+\left\{\frac k{p^j}\right\}+\left\{ \frac x{p^j}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x+k}{p^j}\right\}-1\right)\\
&\geq \sum_{j=1 \\p^j\leq k}^m \left(\left\lfloor \frac k{p^j}\right\rfloor -1\right) \geq \sum_{j=1}^m \left\lfloor \frac k{p^j}\right\rfloor - \frac{\log k}{\log p}.
\end{align}
$$
Hence,
$$
\nu(x;k)\leq \frac{(x+1)\cdots (x+k)}{\prod_{p\leq k} \left( p^{\sum_{j=1}^m \left\lfloor \frac k{p^j}\right\rfloor - \frac{\log k}{\log p}}\right)}\leq \frac{(x+1)\cdots (x+k)}{k!} \cdot \prod_{p\leq k} k.
$$
By Mertens' estimate, $\prod_{p\leq k} k\leq k^{ck/\log k}=e^{ck}$.
Therefore, the desired estimate
$$
\nu(x;k)\leq \frac{(x+k)^ke^{ck}}{k!} \leq \left(\frac{c'(x+k)}k\right)^k
$$
follows.

To show that this estimate is best possible, we use again
$$\begin{align}
\nu_p((x+1) &\cdots (x+k))-\nu_p(\nu(x;k)) \\
&=\sum_{j=1 \\p^j\leq k}^m \left(\left\lfloor \frac k{p^j}\right\rfloor+\left\{\frac k{p^j}\right\}+\left\{ \frac x{p^j}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x+k}{p^j}\right\}-1\right)\\
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^m \left\lfloor \frac k{p^j}\right\rfloor
\end{align}.
$$
Then
$$
\nu(x;k)\geq \frac{(x+1)\cdots (x+k)}{k!},
$$
which shows that the exponent cannot be reduced below $1$.